# Firefox и thunderbird очень медленно запускаются (Manjaro XFCE)

Tags: firefox, thunderbird

С недавних пор сии программы стали ну очень медленно запускаться. Переустановка не помогла. Запуск прог секунд 30. Не подскажете куда рыть?

Answer (score 1):

Смотри, есть несколько вариантов.

1. У тебя в этих браузерах слишком много расширений, и при каждом запуске браузер их долго запускает. Поудаляй лишние.
2. Очень много места занимают история и/или закладки. Почисть их.
3. Может дело в вирусах, которая завелись на компьютере. Проверь хорошим антивирусом.
4. Если ничего не помогает, попробуй другие браузеры (Yandex, Google).

А вообще нужно знать, только ли браузеры тупят. Если не только, значит нужно почистить временные файлы, поправить реестр и т. п.